# How should I configure my repository to handle submodules but still get the folder structure in a certain way?

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules, symlink

I have a git repository with folder "Project" and various subfolders. Two of those subfolders contain library blocks and I want to have those two folders live inside a submodule so it can also be used by a second project in its own repo.
The issue is the software we use requires a specific folder structure. Say the directories are:

Project/
├─A
├─B
├─C
└─D

where folders C and D should be in a submodule. Now I have only managed to get it to work by either creating a submodule for folder C and another for folder D (but this has the disadvantage of making the development process and branching structure more complex as two sub repos have to be managed), and another method was to create a "Library" folder under D as a submodule that contains the folders C and D. However, the folders will then live one directory lower. The software needs those folders to be right under the folder Project. I have not found a way to check out the submodule directly under Project without the Library folder above it.

An idea I had was to keep folders C and D under the Library folder as one submodule but then use Symbolic Links to get the contents of folders C and D back under the Project folder (Windows symbolic links for context). However, I can't seem to get this to commit correctly so that the symbolic links get cloned correctly on another machine. I did check that symlinks is set to true in the git config file on both machines. It seems to just stage the symlink as a file with the path inside it as text.
This is what I would like to achieve:

Project/
├─A
├─B
├─C (symlink)
├─D (symlink)
└─Library (submodule)
│ ├─C
│ ├─D

Is there a way to get this to work in any way? Are there other methods that I have not thought of yet?
Any help would be appreciated.

As stated before, I have tried the symlinks but it does not seem to commit correctly or get cloned correctly. I have tried getting the submodule to be checked out right under the folder project in order to have the directory:

Project/
├─A
├─B
├─C (part of submodule "Library")
├─D (part of submodule "Library")

I get the error stating that "project" is not a submodule. Therefore I can only manage to check it out one directory lower:

Project/
├─A
├─B
└─Library (submodule)
│ ├─C
│ ├─D

but then the software will automatically create an empty folder C and D under project as it expects them to be there, even though the contents are in the submodule under the Library folder.